# how to rebuild osquery app on mac os using open source code of osquery?

Tags: macos, osquery

I want build osquery app for mac os. I followed process https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/building/
mentioned in documentation but it only builds osqueryd binary I need it in form of osquery.app.
How do I do that?
can anyone help me with proper steps to generate osquery.app?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the packaging scripts in https://github.com/osquery/osquery-packaging to apply to the built binaries you have.

Be aware this will not be a signed/entitled app bundle, so the Endpoint Security tables will not function until it is signed that way.

Comment: hi..Mike thanks for sharing it..Can you please help me with steps to build app?